# How to convert CharSequence to Date?

Tags: java, string

I have CharSequence inside it I have Date Like
CharSequence startDate="1998/10/05";
I need date format like DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: See `LocalDate.parse()` and `LocalDate.format()`, along with `DateTimeFormatter` to specify the format.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class to parse and generate text in various formats.

```
DateTimeFormatter in = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd" ) ; 
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1998/10/05" , in ) ;

DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ; 
String output = ld.format( out ) ;
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for exchanging date-time values textually.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CharSequence date = "1996/12/25";
        CharSequence formattedDate = date.subSequence(8, 10) + "/" + date.subSequence(5, 7) + "/"
            + date.subSequence(0, 4);

        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you don't care about validation at all, maybe. It would be better IMO to parse it to `LocalDate` and then format it back again in the format you want.